# How to set 'php setcookie' for html select dropdown

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, select, cookies

I have a jquery ui dialog with an input type in which i put a postcode so people can search with their postcode.

Now i want to make a dropdown with a radius from 5 to 25km.

How can i do this? since i'm new to the setcookie option.

My dropdown code

```
<select>
    <option disabled selected>Afstand</option>
    <option>5km</option>
    <option>10km</option>
    <option>15km</option>
    <option>25km</option>
</select>
```

This is my cookie code + the dialog div:

```
<div id="dialog" class="hidden" title="Welkom bij OostWestRegioBest.nl">

    Zoeken in uw regio.

    <br/><br/>

    <form method="post" action"">
        <input type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="postcode">
        <br/><br/>
            // 
            **// Here will be my select dropdown**
            //
        <input type="submit" value="Opslaan">
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
        <input type="hidden" name="afstand" value="true" />
    </form>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['postcode']))
    {
        setcookie('postcode', $_POST['postcode'], time() + (20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
        header("location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");
    };

?>
```

and here my code to show the cookie for the postcode:

```
<input type="text" name="postcode" value='<?php echo isset($_COOKIE['postcode']) ? $_COOKIE['postcode'] : '' ?>'>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using codeigniter (like your tags suggest), why on earth are you programming your forms like this?

Comment: I'm using php cookies and i think it's easier to implement those things with a normal html form. it doesn't matter. it works and it's easy to read.

Comment: Remember that to set cookies, it needs to happen in the headers, before anything else is output to the browser.

Comment: Yeah forgot that. but that's not relevant on this question, but i will change it.

Comment: @KeesSonnema: It is relevant... move the `if (isset($_POST))`-bit to the top, to ensure that there is no output prior to any cookies being set

Comment: did that. thanks. but that did not solve my problem. that's what i mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to set cookies with Javascript instead of using PHP, so you don't need to reload any page.

EDIT:

if you submit both values (postcode and radius) in the same form you can just add

```
setcookie('radius', $_POST['radius'], time() + (20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
```

right after your first `setcookie()`. Your dropdown should be named radius, so: `<select name="radius">`

Comment: Wrong, relying on JS only is about the worst idea ever: older versions of IE, JS disabled browsers...? What about them?

Comment: i need to show the cookie directly after closing the jquery dialog. so php was the easiest solution

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem He's using jQueryUI, so there shouldn't be a problem with older versions of IE or disabled JS, they won't work in first place.

Comment: but @Uby this is more of an comment instead of a good answer. so you better delete it to avoid downvotes.

Comment: I have an input field where i print the cookie out. i will add that code to OP

Comment: @Uby: cookies still need a jQ plugin, that is blocked in IE7 (which isn't EOL'ed). Nor can it deal with _JS disabled clients_

Comment: @KeesSonnema I'm kinda confused, you were asking about a way to store radius cookie

Comment: maybe it was a bit unclear. but i don't know how to do that. updated my question

Comment: this does not set any cookie called radius. i don't know why?

Comment: Does `$_POST['radius']` contain the right value? Are you setting cookies before headers are sent?

Comment: it works after your edit thanks. i missed the name="radius" part

Comment: @Uby: That rather depends: if you're using jQUI to anumate certain menu's then it's no big disaster. If you're relying on JS to do some site-critical operations: IE set cookies in, then you should care about all users, however mad they might be.

Comment: Please go to chat instead of chatting here. it's very unprofessional